# How to remove duplicate rows and keep highest values only for a gene list with scores

Tags: r, bash, awk

i have a three columns table of 20k lines. 1st column: list of gene IDs (there can be duplicated IDs) 
2nd column: a constant string
3rd column: a value
What i want is to rank my list leaving with only unique gene IDs. For the duplicated gene IDs i want to leave only the ones with the highest score.

here an example, Thanks in advance

```
TMCS09g1008699  ensembl 6.4
TMCS09g1008671  ensembl 6.4
TMCS09g1008672  ensembl 6.5
TMCS09g1008673  ensembl 6
TMCS09g1008674  ensembl 5.4
TMCS09g1008675  ensembl 5.4
TMCS09g1008676  ensembl 4.9
TMCS09g1008677  ensembl 4.6
TMCS09g1008677  ensembl 4.4
TMCS09g1008679  ensembl 4.3
TMCS09g1008680  ensembl 3.9
TMCS09g1008681  ensembl 3.8
TMCS09g1008682  ensembl 3.6
TMCS09g1008683  ensembl 3.5
TMCS09g1008684  ensembl 3.5
TMCS09g1008685  ensembl 3.4
TMCS09g1008686  ensembl 3.4
TMCS09g1008687  ensembl 3.4
TMCS09g1008688  ensembl 3
TMCS09g1008689  ensembl 2.6
TMCS09g1008690  ensembl 2
TMCS09g1008699  ensembl 5.9
```

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: If you're using the `tidyverse` in `r`, you could do: `df %>% group_by(gene) %>% top_n(1, value)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `sort`:

```
sort -k3rn file | sort -u -k1,1
```

The first sort sorts the file by the 3rd column (`k3`) numerically (`n`) in descending order (`r`), the second one uniques the output based on the first column.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following `awk` and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk '{b[$1]=a[$1]>$NF?b[$1]?b[$1]:$0:$0;a[$1]=a[$1]>$NF?a[$1]:$NF;} END{for(i in a){print b[i]}}'  Input_file
```

Adding a non-one liner form of solution too now.

```
awk '
{
  b[$1]=a[$1]>$NF?b[$1]?b[$1]:$0:$0;
  a[$1]=a[$1]>$NF?a[$1]:$NF}
END{
  for(i in a){
    print b[i]}
}
'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use awk for this:

- Store the highest score per gene ID in an array

  - Scan the input
  - If the score is higher than what was seen before, replace it
- In the end, print the content of the array

Here's one way to do that:

```
awk '{ m[$1] = m[$1] > $3 ? m[$1] : $3; } END { for (i in m) print i, "ensembl", m[i] }' file
```

If you would like to see the output sorted by gene ID, then simply pipe the above awk to `sort`.